# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Managing Command Timeout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powerbuilder

We have a powerbuilder application which connects to SQL Server 2008 database. We have some reports which run around 3-4 hours. This is via a procedure invoked from the application code. when this long report runs, the application is getting disconnected from the database after 1 hour 40 minutes.

We have the below timeout parameters set in the connection string from application:
Connect timeout = 6000, TimeOut = 6000,CommandTimeOut = 6000

When we increased the CommandTimeOut Parameter to a higher value, the reports were completed with out database disconnect. But the performance was reduced. ie the reports are taking more time when we increased the value of CommandTimeout parameter in the connection string.

Could you please let me know what is the best solution for this issue.

Comment: `When we increased the CommandTimeOut Parameter to a higher value, the reports were completed with out database disconnect. But the performance was reduced. ie the reports are taking more time when we increased the value of CommandTimeout parameter in the connection string` this will not happen ,look out for wait stats when the query is running

Comment: We have below three parameters used in the connection string:
Connect timeout = 6000, TimeOut = 6000,CommandTimeOut = 6000
If we need to increase commandtimeout, do we need to increase all other timeout parameters with the same value ? what is the good practice ?

Comment: Also is it mandatory to use the above timeout parameters in the connection string ? when i tried to remove the above timeout parameters from the connection string. The procedure execution stops in few seconds and no records will be retrieved.
I read somewhere that, if we set command timeout = 0, then there wont be any limit for the query execution time. But when i tried command timeout = 0, The procedure execution stops in few seconds and no records will be retrieved.

Comment: Possibly: Remote Query Timeout parameter? For remote stored procedures, remote query timeout specifies the number of seconds that must elapse after sending a remote EXECstatement before the remote stored procedure times out.
The setting takes effect immediately without a server stop and restart.
Set to 0 to disabled the timeout. Query will wait until canceled.